# Boost Fusion/MPL: convert type from sequence to sequence of equivalent any_range's

Tags: c++, templates, boost, boost-mpl, boost-fusion

I want to use Boost's `any_range` to handle multiple heterogeneous data ranges.  The type of my data ranges is known as a Fusion vector, for example:

```
typedef vector<double, int, char> TypeSequence
```

Given such a type, I want to write a template to derive a further type like this:

```
vector<AnyRange<double>::value, AnyRange<int>::value, AnyRange<char>::value>
```

where `AnyRange` is defined as:

```
using namespace boost;
template <typename T>
struct AnyRange
{
    typedef typename any_range<typename T, forward_pass_traversal_tag, int, std::ptrdiff_t> value;
};
```

I've tried and failed.  Is this even possible with Fusion?  MPL?  Or perhaps I'm heading down the wrong path with `any_range`.

Comment: It should definitely be possible - However, it looks more like you would want to convert from an MPL vector (one without actual data) into a fusion vector (one with data). Also, your use of "typename" looks a bit off...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily using [boost::mpl::transform](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/transformation/metafunctions/transform.html), which you can use with Fusion sequences (as long as you include the appropriate headers to make Fusion sequences behave as confirming MPL sequences):

```
#include <boost/range/any_range.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp> // Required to adapt Fusion to MPL
#include <boost/fusion/include/vector.hpp>

#include <boost/mpl/transform.hpp>


template < typename T >
struct EmbedInAnyRange
{
    typedef boost::any_range< // no need for typename here
        T,                    // no need for typename here
        forward_pass_traversal_tag, 
        int,                  // not sure what this parameter is, I leave int...
        std::ptrdiff_t
    > type;
};

int main()
{
    typedef boost::fusion::vector< double, int, char > Tuple;

    typedef boost::mpl::transform<
        Tuple,
        EmbedInAnyRange< boost::mpl::_ >
    >::type AnyRangeTuple;

    AnyRangeTuple myTuple( 
        std::vector< double >(), 
        std::list< int >(), 
        std::vector< char >() );
}
```

If you want, you can put the transformation into its own metafunction:

```
template < typename Seq >
struct EmbedAllInAnyRange
{
    typedef typename boost::mpl::transform< // typename needed
        Seq,
        EmbedInAnyRange< boost::mpl::_ >
    >::type type;
};

...

typedef EmbedAllInRange< Tuple >::type AnyRangeTuple;
```

Comment: Worth noting that `#include <boost/fusion/mpl.hpp>` (or ...`/include/mpl.hpp`) is required here. Contrary to the docs, boost fusion sequences are not automatically MPL sequences, at least not without including this header file. Failing to include this header can lead to some very obscure (even for MPL) error messages.

Comment: @Luc Touraille: I can only confirm what @Alastair wrote here and thus suggest an edit with a big fat note on inclusion of `<boost/fusion/include/mpl.hpp>`. Just ran into that problem with really strange error message: `error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'boost::mpl::clear_impl<boost::fusion::fusion_sequence_tag>::apply<boost::fusion::vector<...`.